# qmake.conf and project files from parent direcory

Tags: qt5, qmake

I noticed that if you include your project ( framework in my case) file in you main .pro file like this:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS += \
    ../framework \
    plugins \
    apps

OTHER_FILES += \
    .qmake.conf
```

.qmake.conf file settings will not be applied to the framework.pro from ../framework/framework.pro

Is this normal?

Well from other side, is this normal way how I organising this project ? Idea is to include framework project which is common to bunch of other projects, and can be build with the project in one shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.qmake.conf is searched in current and parent directory. That means than when qmake will build framework.pro it will search .qmake.conf in a parent directory, and won't find it.